# AWS Glue job creates duplicate record in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have used AWS glue studio. I picked all the options that I needed from the Glue Studio UI. Let me try to explain little more and shared default job script code in the bottom..

1. Created a Connection with AWS RDS in the glue.
2. Created a database **education_earnings_dev** in the Glue Data catalog,
3. Created a crawler in the glue to sync **courses** from the RDS which created a new table **courses** under database **education_earnings_dev**.
4. Created a Glue job in the AWS Glue Studio to create a table inside Athena. This process will save Parquet formatted data file inside S3.

Everything works fine what I have wanted. The issue is..
example - RDS **courses** table has 2 rows with id=1 and id=2. So, glue job created two files in S3 and created the table in Athena after running for the first time. I can see those rows in Athena. But when I run the Job one more time. I can see 4 rows in Athena table . There are 2 id=1 and 2 id=2 (Duplicate records). If I run one more time, there will be more duplicates. How can I avoid this?

```python
    import sys
    from awsglue.transforms import *
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    from awsglue.job import Job
    
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)
    
    # Script generated for node Courses AWS Glue Data Catalog
    CoursesAWSGlueDataCatalog_node1639083038099 = (
        glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
            database="education_earnings_dev",
            table_name="ebdb_courses",
            transformation_ctx="CoursesAWSGlueDataCatalog_node1639083038099",
        )
    )
    
    # Script generated for node Amazon S3
    AmazonS3_node1639084410044 = glueContext.getSink(
        path="s3://orca-education-api/big-data/dev/education_earning/source/courses/",
        connection_type="s3",
        updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
        partitionKeys=[],
        compression="snappy",
        enableUpdateCatalog=True,
        transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1639084410044",
    )
    AmazonS3_node1639084410044.setCatalogInfo(
        catalogDatabase="education_earnings_dev", catalogTableName="courses"
    )
    AmazonS3_node1639084410044.setFormat("glueparquet")
    AmazonS3_node1639084410044.writeFrame(CoursesAWSGlueDataCatalog_node1639083038099)
    job.commit()
```

Final step in glue job where I defined the s3 location and table name [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post relevant code that would help to understand the question deeper? For example: the glue job, the table schema of the RDS and Athena.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Job Bookmarks. It's just a predefined variable that you need to send in your Glue:Job creation.

[Tracking Processed Data Using Job Bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html#monitor-continuations-implement)

| AWS Glue version | Amazon S3 source formats |
| --- | --- |
| Version 0.9 | JSON, CSV, Apache Avro, XML |
| Version 1.0 and later | JSON, CSV, Apache Avro, XML, Parquet, ORC |

The command that needs to be sent is inside DefaultArguments:

```
'--job-bookmark-option': 'job-bookmark-enable'
```

full example:

```
GlueJob:
        Type: 'AWS::Glue::Job'
        Properties:
            Role: !Ref AWSGlueServiceRole
            Description: Job created with CloudFormation
            GlueVersion: '3.0'
            Command:
                Name: glueetl
                PythonVersion: '3'
                ScriptLocation: !Sub 's3://${ArtifactBucketName}/scripts/GlueCrawlerDynamodb.py'
            ExecutionProperty:
                MaxConcurrentRuns: 2
            DefaultArguments:
                {
                    '--job-bookmark-option': 'job-bookmark-enable',
                }
            MaxRetries: 3
            WorkerType: 'G.1X'
            NumberOfWorkers: 5
            Name: !Join
                - '-'
                - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
                  - etljob
```

Documentation talking about: [Special Parameters Used by Amazon Glue](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html)